# Recent SQL Version Survey Results

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I am looking for a recent survey of SQL server versions in use in businesses. I have found one dating back to Aug 2013, bit a lot can change in a year and a half. From what I can see, 2008 is the most popular version.

I hope you can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plurality in use today I would say is SQL Server 2008 R2 (which many consider 2010). SQL Server is generally supported ten years. If MS stops support many organizations will not allow it to run (due to worries about it being hacked) so most (whatever that means) will upgrade when a product is within a year or two of going out of MS support (or a year after it has gone out of support).

Because of this many organizations are now installing SQL Server 2012 anticipating that they won't have to upgrade until 2020-2022. However once the support people and network people are used to a version its (very) difficult to get them to upgrade so there are many, many organizations still installing new installs of SQL Server 2008R2.

That said SQL Server 2014 has many excellent new features (Hekaton,Resource Governer for IO, updateable columnstore indexes etc) and its been around for over a year (and sp1 is about to be re-released) so if I have any say in it and there are no institutional issues I would go with SQL Server 2014.